# Apache Spark: Error on JavaSparkContext.stop()

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When my spark program calls JavaSparkContext.stop(), the following errors occur.

```
14/12/11 16:24:19 INFO Main: sc.stop {
14/12/11 16:24:20 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster02,38918) not found
14/12/11 16:24:20 ERROR SendingConnection: Exception while reading SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster04,59659)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureReadOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:252)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.network.SendingConnection.read(Connection.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$6.run(ConnectionManager.scala:205)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
14/12/11 16:24:20 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster03,59821) not found
14/12/11 16:24:20 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster02,38918) not found
14/12/11 16:24:20 WARN ConnectionManager: All connections not cleaned up
14/12/11 16:24:20 INFO Main: sc.stop }
```

How can I fix this?

The configuration is as follows:

- Spark version is 1.1.1
- Client runs on Windows 7
- The cluster is Linux(CentOS 6.5).
- spark.master=yarn-client
- Since Spark has a problem submitting job from Windows to Linux, I applied my patch to the Spark source code. (Please see https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/899 )

**UPDATE**

When the Spark client runs on Linux, following errors occur. (I think it's basically the same errors)

```
14/12/12 11:32:02 INFO Main: sc.stop {
14/12/12 11:32:02 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://clientmachine:4040
14/12/12 11:32:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
14/12/12 11:32:02 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
14/12/12 11:32:02 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
14/12/12 11:32:02 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster04,52869)
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster04,52869)
14/12/12 11:32:03 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster04,52869) not found
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster03,57334)
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster03,57334)
14/12/12 11:32:03 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster03,57334) not found
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster02,54205)
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster02,54205)
14/12/12 11:32:03 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster02,54205) not found
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterActor: MapOutputTrackerActor stopped!
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO ConnectionManager: Selector thread was interrupted!
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster02,54205)
14/12/12 11:32:03 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster02,54205) not found
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster04,52869)
14/12/12 11:32:03 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cluster04,52869) not found
14/12/12 11:32:03 WARN ConnectionManager: All connections not cleaned up
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO ConnectionManager: ConnectionManager stopped
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
14/12/12 11:32:03 INFO Main: sc.stop }
```

Comment: Do you also get this error when running the client on Linux?

Comment: @DanielDarabos I have not run it on Linux. But 1.0.0 had no such problem on Windows 7.

Comment: @DanielDarabos I've run it on Linux. Please see the UPDATE on the question. I think it's basically the same error.

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. Hopefully someone who knows the code better will see your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Some threads have suggested to put a Thread.sleep before you do a Spark Context 'stop'. See if that helps.